# Salesforce SOQL Queries and Tags

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, soql, force.com

I'm just getting started with the Salesforce Web Services API and I'm surprised that there isn't an obvious way to do a query for all e.g. Account objects that contain certain tags.

What would you say is the best way to find all objects that contain certain tags?

I imagine it involves a join on Account.id and AccountTag.id or something similar, but despite some real research, I'm not sure how best to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance!

Update: I guess I could do a select from AccountTag and then get the account objects based on ItemId, but the ideal would be to do a query on Account, with Tags being only one part of the criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the SOQL-R style queries to do this, e.g. this will fetch the account Id and account Name for all the accounts with the `internet` tag.

```
select item.id, item.name from accountTag where name='internet'
```

in this case the item relationship is to the account that was tagged, so you can select any field from the account object through the item relationship path.

See the [SOQL-R docs](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm) for more info

Comment: That's really interesting. Thank you. My only other question is whether it is possible with SOQL to do what is described here:

Comment: No i don't think there's anyway to do that in SOQL. (and please remember to accept this answer if it answers your original question)

Comment: You totally answered my original question, and thank you! My (new) question is when I run that query for multiple tags, e.g. 'internet' and 'web'

Comment: ...I am going to get duplicate Account records -- and I'm wondering if it is possible to get the effect of one Account record, with a comma separated list of tags.

Comment: You can't get the comma separated list of tags, the closest would be to get the child collection of tags, and make the comma list from them, e.g.select id, name, (select name from tags) from account where id in (select itemId from accountTag where name='web' or name='internet') but for some reason that semi-join filter is not supported, so i don't know of any easy way to do this.

Comment: @superfell, thanks for the name of the Tags relationship for use in subqueries.